# multiparti image upload issue

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

Please note before everything I'd like to mention I'm very new in mean stack.
I got multiparty working in my code however the uploaded image is significantly smaller than original.
Here is what I have in my controller and I appreciate if anyone can point me to the right direction. I'm guessing I'm not reading the stream completely and somehow I drop out:

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty'), fs = require('fs');
exports.postImage = function(req, res) {
var form = new multiparty.Form();
var data = "";
var fname = "";

form.on('part', function(part) {
if (part.filename)
{
        fname = '/Users/guest/Desktop/'+part.filename
        var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fname);
        part.pipe(writeStream);
} 
else 
{
        form.handlePart(part);
    }
});
form.on('close', function()
{
    console.log("Form closes ...");
});
form.parse(req);
```

I also noticed when the upload is done meaning when I get my message "Form closes ..." after a minute or so the following error is thrown:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.onReqAborted (/Users/guest/Desktop/wg-mean/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:183:17)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at abortIncoming (http.js:1911:11)
    at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (http.js:1923:5)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at TCP.close (net.js:465:12)
```

Comment: You mean this all works it's just that the image is visually smaller?

Comment: correct. the above code works. it's just the uploaded image is like 1/10 of the original. Imagine a big image become a small icon size.

Comment: Is this for any image? Or just a specific one?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue which was in my client side.